# Performance std::strstr vs. std::string::find

Tags: c++, gcc, stdstring, strstr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ string::find complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869605/c-stringfind-complexity)

Recently I noticed that the function `std::string::find` is an order of magnitude slower than the function `std::strstr` - in my environment with GCC 4.7 on Linux. The performance difference depends on the lengths of the strings and on the hardware architecture.

There seems to be a simple reason for the difference: `std::string::find` basically calls `std::memcmp` in a loop - with time complexity `O(m * n)`. In contrast, `std::strstr` is highly optimized for the hardware architecture (e.g. with SSE instructions) and uses a more sophisticated string matching algorithm (apparently Knuth-Morris-Pratt).

I was also surprised not to find the time complexities of these two functions in the language documents (i.e. drafts N3290 and N1570). I only found time complexities for `char_traits`. But that doesn't help, because there is no function for substring search in `char_traits`.

I would expect, that `std::strstr` and `memmem` contain similar optimizations with almost identical performance. And until recently, I assumed that `std::string::find` uses `memmem` internally.

**The questions are:** Is there any good reason, why `std::string::find` does not use `std::memmem`? And does it differ in other implementations?

*The question is not:* What is the best implementation of this function? It is really difficult to argue for C++, if it is slower than C. I wouldn't matter if both implementations would be slow. It is the performance difference that really hurts.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Your are right, there is some overlap in the two questions. But my questions are more specific, and the other article answers none of them.

Comment: @nosid: yes it does. Look in particular to the extra explanation in comments by dietmar kuhl about average-case vs worst-case and space-complexity why this is most likely not used. Those arguments don't change if you reuse `std::memmem` iso implementing the algorithm from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what's `memmem`?  I can't find this in the C++ standard, nor the
Posix standard (which contains all of the standard C functions).

Second, any measurement values will depend on the actual data.  Using
KMP, for example, will be a pessimisation in a lot of cases; probably
most of the cases where the member functions of `std::string` are used;
the time to set up the necessary tables will often be more than the
total time of the straightforeward algorithm.  Things like `O(m*n)`
don't mean much when the typical length of the string is short.

Comment: I asssumed, that `memmem` is part of C, but apparently it isn't. `memmem` is to `strstr` what `memcmp` is to `strcmp`. However, I am sure you know that. Nevertheless, as I have already mentioned a few times. The question is not if KMP is a good choice. The question is, why they are using completely different algorithms for `strstr` and `std::string::find`.

Comment: @nosid Perhaps because the expected use pattern is different?  Or because different authors have privileged different use patterns?  In most applications I've seen, most strings are fairly short, with the longest strings corresponding to perhaps a line.  For such strings, using something like KMP would probably be a pessimization.  If the authors of `memmem` thought that the typical use case would involve blocks of several KB of memory or more, on the other hand, it's definitely worthwhile.

Comment: According to my benchmarks, as of 25.06.2013: for GCC, string::find is slightly faster (~10%) (x86_64, -march=native, ran on AWS) - for MSVC 2, times slower (x86, SSE2, on AMD desktop). (full optimizations)