# Time Complexity of find operation

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ string::find complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869605/c-stringfind-complexity)

What is the time complexity of the find operation that comes built-in with the string library in STL?

Comment: N3485 §21.4.7.2 if you want to look it up.

Comment: @chris: All that tells you is that the standard doesn't specify any complexity requirements.

Comment: I didn't get your reference. I mean does it refer to some documentation? I googled it but it only referred me back to this question.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, That's the point. You can't take a complexity value for a function when the standard gives none.

Comment: @tom, http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf

Comment: @tom: It refers (rather cryprically) to the C++ standard. N3485 is a publically available draft of the standard, which you can probably find by googling. 21.4.7.2 is the section of the standard that defines `std::string::find`. But it doesn't specify any complexity requirements.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I suppose it is a bit cryptic when you don't know what it means ;)

Comment: possible dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869605/c-stringfind-complexity

Comment: @tom btw - that link was a couple down in the google results below your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Standard, §21.4.7.2, doesn't give any guarantees as to the complexity.

You can reasonably assume [`std::basic_string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) takes linear time in the length of the string being searched in, though, as even the naïve algorithm (check each substring for equality) has that complexity, and it's unlikely that the `std::string` constructor will build a fancy index structure to enable anything faster than that.

The complexity in terms of the pattern being searched for may reasonably vary between linear and constant, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, standard doesn't specify that.

However, since `std::string` is a generalized container and it can't make any assumptions about the nature of the string it holds, you can reasonably assume that complexity will be  `O(n)` in case when you search for a single `char`.

Comment: But if I wish to match a substring would it still be linear?

Comment: It will be linear, but not `O(n)`, rather `O(n*m)` where `m` is a length of substring being matched

Comment: So I could just use str.find instead of maybe say implementing the KMP algorithm to search for a substring?

Comment: Your implementation could aleady be using KMP. Check it first. if it doesn't and performance is critical, then by all means roll your own

Comment: Note that Boost has a Boyer-Moore, Boyer-Moore-Horspool, and Knuth-Morris-Pratt searching algorithms ready for your use.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Searching.html

Answer (score -3):

At most, performs as many comparisons as the number of elements in the range [first,last).

http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: Once again, this is about `std::string::find`.