# Can It Be Faster to Find the Minimum Periodic String Inside Another String in Terms of Time Complexity

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this ACM problem (`10298 - Power Strings`): http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/102/10298.html

The problem is to find the minimum periodic string inside of another string.  For example:

Test Input:

```
abcd
aaaa
ababab
```

Test Output:

```
1
4
3
```

My idea is:

1. Let `s` be the input string;
2. Make a string `ss` from `s+s`, and shift the first character;
3. Find the first occurrence of `s` in string `ss`.

Below is my code:

```
inline int GetLargestN(const char* cs)
{
    string s(cs);
    string ss(s, 1); ss += s; ss += s[0];

    int len = s.length();
    int pos = ss.find(s);

    return len/(pos+1);
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/ string::find should be O(n)

However, I keep getting Time Limitation Exceeds

NOTES:

1. I also tried my own `find` substring match using Sunday Search, whose time complexity is also O(n), but still TLE.
2. I am NOT a student, so I am NOT asking for home assignment help. I'm a working professional. Solving ACM problems is just my hobby.

Please help.

Comment: I don't see how that function correctly factorizes the power string unless you are using it in a loop, in which case your complexity becomes more like `N^2`.

Comment: Perhaps `string::find` isn't using a linear-time string matching algorithm. Have you tried switching to KMP, Rabin-Karp, or Boyer-Moore?

Comment: @paddy, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/ `string::find` should be `O(n)`

Comment: @templatetypedef, as I mentioned in my post, I tried Sunday Search for substring pattern search. Sunday Search should still be `O(n)`.  I have not tried KMP though, but would that matter, if my algorithm is also `O(n)`?

Comment: I think your solution being TLE just boils down to string ops being really slow, actually. An O(n) solution here: http://f0rth3r3c0rd.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/uva-10298-power-strings/

Comment: @kevmo314, if that algorithm could get accepted, I am gonna cry ........

Comment: @PeterLee don't worry, it's okay. I cry a lot after algorithm competitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I switched to use the native C function strstr, and it got accepted, which does NOT make too much sense!

```
/* Memory allocated in the main function, M is too big, we have to allocate in the heap */
char* s  = new char[M];
char* ss = new char[M*2];

int GetLargestN(const char* s, char* ss)
{
    int n = strlen(s);

    strcpy(ss, s+1); strcpy(ss+n-1, s); ss[n*2] = s[0]; ss[n*2+1] = 0;

    int p = strstr(ss, s)-ss;

    return n/(p+1);
}
```

Here was the submission:

```
#       Problem     Verdict     Language    Run Time    Submission Date
12538969    10298   Power Strings   Accepted    C++     0.135   2013-10-22 03:48:14
12534976    10298   Power Strings   Time limit exceeded     C++     3.000   2013-10-21 07:42:46
12534959    10298   Power Strings   Time limit exceeded     C++     3.000   2013-10-21 07:37:16
12534922    10298   Power Strings   Time limit exceeded     C++     3.000   2013-10-21 07:26:16
12534863    10298   Power Strings   Time limit exceeded     C++     3.000   2013-10-21 07:04:21
```