# What is the complexity of std::string::find?

Tags: c++, string

As given in the title, I'm interested in finding the complexity(upper-bound) of [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method of c++ standard library which gives the position for a sub-string that is being matched. I couldn't find anything on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) page and was wondering if I need to manually role out KMP or some other pattern matching algo if complexity is not up to par.

In case standard does not guarantees any upper limit for such operation, I would like to know what common implementations are present in current versions of compilers and where to find them so that I could check them..

Comment: Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8869605

Comment: Isn't that clear from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)?

Comment: C++17 will ship with two new "searchers", see [func.search]: Boyer-Moore and Boyer-Moore-Horspool.