# Which algorithm is used by string::find in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, time-complexity

I need to search for a sub-string in a given string. C++ provides library function 'find' for this. What is the algorithm used by this library function? For purpose of competitive programming, should I use this function or use KMP search algorithm?

Comment: KMP definitely, find is O(n*k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a quick search, I found this:

- KMP is `O(n + k)`
- Find is `O(n * k)`

So KMP is a faster search algorithm.

[C++ string::find complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869605/)

[Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)