# What would the expression for time complexity be for the following code

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int string_addition(int t) {
    std::string s, x, temp;
    int size1, size2;
    
    cin >> size1 >> size2;
    cin >> s;
    cin >> x;
        
    temp = s;
    int checkval = -1;

    for (int count = 0; count < size2; count++) { 
        bool isFound = s.find(x) != string::npos;
        if (isFound) {
            checkval = count;
                 
            break;
        }

        s += s;  
    }
         
    return checkval;            
}

int main() {
    int test_cases;
    cin >> test_cases;
    for (int i = 0; i < test_cases; i++) {
        int result = string_addition(test_cases);
        cout << result << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Im learning about time and space complexities and was wondering what would its expression be cus for an input of a large magnitude i get time limit exceeded errors,
and also does this approach come under brute force or not

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869605/c-stringfind-complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 loops:

1st in the main, the `for` loop has worst case complexity of `test_cases`.

2nd in string_addition, the `for` loop has worst case complexity `size2`.

3rd is hidden inside the find function, which has time complexity O(n), so in this case `s.size()` which is apparently `size1`. You ought to name variables with more meaningful names.

The overall time complexity should be `O(test_cases * size2 * s.size())`.
The multiplication is due to the nested loops.

Comment: Thanks,  I couldn't figure out how to add the third functions complexity  and it also explains why my code couldn't pass all the test cases and yes I have to start naming variables more accurately